# Connect QEMU VM to Internet with bridge helper

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, qemu

I am using QEMU VM to test OVS-DPDK with virtio-networking. However, I also want a network device to connect to the Internet. So I try to use the bridge helper provided by QEMU.

I follow the instruction in [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q1PebvpQUvI) to create a bridge, and VM.

**(1) Create a bridge**

```
$ sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
```

**(2) Bind a physical NIC to the bridge**

```
$ sudo ip addr flush dev eno2
$ sudo ip link set eno2 master br0
$ brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.1866daf9a071       no              eno2
```

**(3) Set up `br0`**

According to [the blog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248504/bridged-interfaces-do-not-have-internet-access), I think I need to set the IP address of the bridge `br0`. I left `eno2` unconfigured.

```
$ sudo ifconfig br0 10.0.0.21/8
$ ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:66:da:f9:a0:71
          inet addr:10.0.0.21  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1a66:daff:fef9:a071/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13028 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:694896 (694.8 KB)  TX bytes:2832 (2.8 KB)

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:66:da:f9:a0:70
          inet addr:10.0.0.20  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1a66:daff:fef9:a070/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:229486 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17595899 (17.5 MB)  TX bytes:1923061 (1.9 MB)
          Interrupt:89

eno2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:66:da:f9:a0:71
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5016 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:349069 (349.0 KB)  TX bytes:5332 (5.3 KB)
          Interrupt:90
```

**Note:** I have two physical NICs. One is `eno1`, for host network. The other is `eno2`, just for VM, which is not configured in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

**(4) Create VM with bridge helper**

Create VM

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm  -m 1024 -smp 2 -nographic \
    -chardev socket,id=char0,path=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/vhost-user2 \
    -netdev type=vhost-user,id=mynet1,chardev=char0,vhostforce \
    -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet1,mac=52:54:00:02:d9:02 \
    -object memory-backend-file,id=mem,size=1024M,mem-path=/dev/hugepages,share=on \
    -numa node,memdev=mem -mem-prealloc \
    -net nic -net bridge,br=br0 \
    $IMAGE_DIR/debian_squeeze_amd64_standard.qcow2
```

Here I use the image from [Debian](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/amd64/). I set up a `vhost-user` port, which is generated by OVS-DPDK. I guess this does not have an effect on the bridge.

The most important part is: `-net nic -net bridge,br=br0`.

**(5) Enter the VM**

After entering the VM, I found bridge helper automatically create a tap interface in host:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.1866daf9a071       no              eno2
                                                        tap0
```

In VM, I found that the bridge port (`eth0`) and the vhost-user port (`eth2`):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:287 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:17220 (16.8 KiB)  TX bytes:2520 (2.4 KiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:02:d9:02
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:560 (560.0 B)  TX bytes:560 (560.0 B)
```

Then, the VM has no connection to neither the Internet or the host.

Thank you for sharing the idea.

Comment: I am curtrently also struggling with similar problems and I also found the video you posted, which is great. But still nothing works... What I found was that you are using the old `-netdev` / `-device` together with newer `-nic` command. I found some info here: https://www.qemu.org/2018/05/31/nic-parameter/

Answer (score -1):

There 2 methods I deploy without use of extra bridge to achieve the desired connection.

1. for internet access `-net user,hostfwd=tcp::10023-:22 -net nic` and DPDK port as `-chardev socket,id=char0,path=/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/vhost-user2 -netdev type=vhost-user,id=mynet1,chardev=char0,vhostforce -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet1,mac=52:54:00:02:d9:02`.
2. Another alternative is to allow `NAT` interface towards HOST and run DHCP to get IP address in the guest.